# error estimate or confidence interval on a probability

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, inference, error

Imagine I have $N$ 6-sided die, all identical but not fair, so that the probability of getting 1 is $P(1)$, the probability of getting 2 is $P(2)$ etc.  I would like to run an experiment (rather than simulation) to estimate the probability $P(S)$ of obtaining a certain sum $S$ of the faces of these $N$ die.

So I buy a robot (or cheaper yet: hire a student!) to repeatedly throw these $N$ die and make a table of the sums of faces.  After $n$ throws (say $n=10^6$) , the target sum $S$ has been recorded $n_s$ times.  How does one estimate the error on $n_s$ as a function of $n$?

There is no constraint on $N$ other than it’s “large enough”  to justify doing the experiment rather than actually doing the calculation (for definiteness $N$ can be chosen to be $50$), and $n_s$ is so that $n_s/n$ is “small”, i.e. the outcome $S$ has low probability.

My original thought was to get the robot to make multiple runs of $n=10^6$ throws, and do statistics (averaging etc) on these runs, but somehow that doesn't seem to be right: there is no "experimental error" on $P(S)$, so I'm not sure conceptually what is the relevance of averaging, as I would do if I could expect variations in the result based on different experimental conditions.  Moreover, the number $n=10^6$ is otherwise arbitrary so I can artificially increase the number of runs by making $n$ smaller.

(I will settle for a reference to a paper or textbook describing how to work it out.)

Comment: In what sense is there "no experimental error on $P(S)$"? It would seem that either you are using $P(S)$ to refer to the theoretical *but not directly observable* chance, which means referring to experimental error is meaningless, or you are referring to the *estimate* $n_s/n,$ which obviously is subject to experimental error!  It may also be worth asking why you posit such an elaborate setup for the purpose of estimating a *single* probability: this looks to be no different than tossing a coin a million times to estimate its chance of heads. How does your situation differ?

Comment: @whuber If I take 20 samples of soil from an acre to measure water concentration, I expect there will be variations from one sample to the next because the water may not be uniformly distributed.  Then I can take an average of these as an estimate of the amount of water in the soil.  Here, I cannot take 20 samples of my $P(S)$.  As to the second part of your comment: maybe it is as simple as what you suggest, although the different probabilities of rolling a $1$, a $2$ or etc (superficially at least) make it more complicated... (or I myself am making it more complicated).

Comment: I think you may be mixing up two different things: $P(S)$ is the chance the sum is $S.$  Although you don't sample it, your samples allow you to estimate $P(S),$ because the distribution of the count $n_s$ is Binomial with parameters $n$ and $P(S).$  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+confidence+score%3A5 for many highly-voted posts on the topic.

Comment: @whuber yes your comment made me realize things were not clear in my mind.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N$ is large enough, you can compute a confidence interval using the formula:
$$
\frac{n_j}{N} \pm \frac{z}{N}\sqrt{\frac{(n_j)(N - n_j)}{N}} \\
$$
where $N$ is the total number of dice rolls, $n_j$ is the number of time that face $j$ appeared and $z$ is related with the confidence level. For a $95\%$ confidence interval, $z \approx 1.96$.

Equivalently, if you already have the probabilities $P(j)$:
$$
P(j) \pm z\sqrt{\frac{P(j)(1 - P(j))}{N}}
$$

---

**Edit:**

The formula above is the [Normal approximation interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Normal_approximation_interval) for the Binomial distribution.
Other more precise and more complex formulas exist, for instance, the Wilson interval with continuity correction $( w^- , w^+ )$, where:

$$
\begin{align}
  w^- &= \frac { 2 N P(j) + z^2 - A } { 2(N + z^2) }
     \\
  w^+ &= \frac { 2 N P(j) + z^2 + A } { 2(N + z^2) }
\end{align}
$$
with $A = 1 + z \sqrt{z^2 - \frac{1}{N} + 4 N P(j)(1 - P(j)) - 4P(j) + 2}$

If $P(1)=0$ or $w^- < 0$, then $w^-$ must be set to $0$.
Similarly, if $P(1)=1$ or $w^+ > 1$, then $w^+$ must be set to $1$.

You may also check [a pdf by Wallis](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/english-usage/staff/sean/resources/binomialpoisson.pdf)  with more detail on these types of formulas.

Comment: if you're so kind as to add a standard reference to this it would help me a lot with future like problems.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I've added a couple of references and another, more precise, formula.